# Category array values is empty in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a seperaed .php file and that is located in root folder. Which all are the code i need to include to get the magento predefined function. The following code i run in server and the getting category array values is null

```
require_once('/var/www/html/app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
mysql_select_db('test');

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('40185');
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
   $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
   print_r($_cat);
}
```

**Result**

```
 Mage_Catalog_Model_Category Object (

     [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_category
     [_eventObject:protected] => category
     [_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_category
     [_useFlatResource:protected] => 1
     [_designAttributes:Mage_Catalog_Model_Category:private] => Array
         (
             [0] => custom_design
             [1] => custom_design_from
             [2] => custom_design_to
             [3] => page_layout
             [4] => custom_layout_update
             [5] => custom_apply_to_products
         )

     [_treeModel:protected] => 
     [_urlModel:protected] => 
     [_defaultValues:protected] => Array
         (
         )

     [_storeValuesFlags:protected] => Array
         (
         )

     [_lockedAttributes:protected] => Array
         (
         )

     [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1
     [_isReadonly:protected] => 
     [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/category_flat
     [_resource:protected] => 
     [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/category_flat_collection
     [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
     [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
     [_data:protected] => Array
         (
             [store_id] => 1
         )

     [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
     [_origData:protected] => Array
         (
             [store_id] => 1
         )

     [_idFieldName:protected] => 
     [_isDeleted:protected] => 
     [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
         (
         )

     [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
         (
         )

 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add bellow code in your file

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

echo '<pre>';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(40185);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
   $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
   print_r($_cat);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try with following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('40185');

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_category->getName();
}
```

Also use $_category->getData(), to get the other details of category. It returns the array of category info.